# Creating a simple zoo series from YYYY-MM-TT to YYYY-MM-TT

Tags: r, xts, zoo

can you help me for the following question?
I have a large excel-file which looks like that:

[Click here to view a screenshot for the excel file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KVP5m.png)

Imagine these are the stock prices of four different companies.
On the first column you see the dates of a few days of 2010 in YY.MM.DD and
on the first row you see the company-no. like 101, 102 ...
So company 101 had a stock price of 4,555 dollar on the first day of the year.

Now I have to create a zoo series in R for the `eventstudies` package.

[Click here to view a screenshot for the description](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qsLUk.png)

What's the fastest way to create a format like these? I had a lot of tries but I didn't get the right solution. The values has to look like these:

[Click here to view a screenshot for the final zoo series](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pmUQn.png)

The date has now the format YYYY-MM-DD. As you see we have in this `zoo` series some values with minus. So it shows the changes from day 1 to day 2.

My final `zoo` series would show for company 101 a value of +1 for every day starting in 2010-01-04.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple:

```
library(zoo)
library(openxlsx)

sheet <- read.xlsx("<path to your excel doc.xlsx>")
dates <- as.Date(sheet[[1]], format = "%m.%d.%y") 
# if this doesn't work, replace 1 with your column name

startdate <- min(dates)
enddate <- max(dates)
dates <- seq(startdate, enddate, by = "day")
dates_zoo <- as.xts(dates)
```

Answer (score 0):

to convert the dates, use

```
new_data_variable <- as.Date(old_date_variable, "%m.%d.%y")
```

If you're looking to reshape the data as well, there are many options available, but I'm not certain what you need in that respect.

Comment: Hi Melissa, thank you for your response! I Need a zoo object like in the third screenshot. Can you tell me a way to create this with my excel file like in screenshot one?

Comment: It's not about the form of the date.

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest way is to combine as.xts() with seq.Date(), like this:

```
startdate <- as.Date("2010-01-01")
enddate <- as.Date("2010-12-31")
timeseries <- as.xts(x = seq.Date(from = startdate, to = enddate, by = "1 day"))
```

EDIT

Perhaps this is closer to what you want:

```
x <- readxl::read_excel("filename.xlsx")
x$X__1 <- lubridate::dmy(x$X__1)
as.zoo(x)
```

Comment: Hi, thank you. But my question is how can I import this excel file to a zoo object?

Comment: Andy, is this what you mean?